# Couldn't build with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: debugging, build, microsoft-metro

I couldn't build and run the project in Visual Studio 2012. I run the same project on another Windows 8 PC. It works very well. One hour before it becomes like that, I was asked "You PC needs to restart. Do you want to restart". I said "Yes". After restarting my PC, all projects cannot be able to run and build. Please, somebody tell me that what should I do?

Comment: Roy Dictus, I did it. I didn't know much about it. So, do you have some ideas about my questions?

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand the question. You say that after you restarted your PC, your project builds, right? Or do I misunderstand your text?

Comment: yes. Even though it becomes over 10 mins, the project is still building and can't finish.